# Truth set of (p ∧ q) → ¬r and venn diagram of this?

Tags: propositional-calculus

[Venn Diagram Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZID2.png)

I am struggling to understand truth sets and the symbols used.

In this context $P, Q, R$ are truth sets of $p,q,r$.

I am unsure of how to find the truth set of this expression
$$
(p ∧ q) \to \neg r
$$
And how to represent in a venn diagram

Would the diagram be something like this?

Comment: Hint: Convert the implication to a disjunction via the identity $p\to q\iff \neg p\lor q$.

Comment: Am I along the right lines with the venn diagram?

Comment: I don't know. I didn't compute it. I just know that if you do the conversion you will be working with "ands" and "ors" which are easy to express with Venn diagrams.

Comment: How do I express in terms of truth sets? So (p ∪ (q ∩ r)) etc?

Comment: If, by truth set, you mean the set of values that satisfy the expression then you can construct the truth table and see which values of $p$, $q$ and $r$ lead to true outcomes for the expression. In fact, you can do that without converting the implication and construct the Venn diagram from that.

Comment: I am fine with truth tables and the venn diagram, just unsure of truth sets. So for the above expression, I am unsure whether it is P∩Q∩R or something else

Comment: Your diagram cannot be correct because you have drawn $p\land q\land r$ but your expression says that an element in $p\land q$ cannot be in $r$.

Comment: So what would you suggest it would be?

Comment: Try one or both of the suggestions above. You'll get it.

Comment: I have tried both but am still unclear.

Answer (score 1):

See Lipschutz, Schaum's Outline Of Discrete mathematics ( Index : " truth set").

The truth set of a proposition is the set of all cases in which this proposition is true.

Here, the " cases" are represented by lists ( ordered sets) of truth-values ( True/False): couples of truth-values if your formula has 2 atomic propositions, triples of truth-values if it has 3, etc.

So the truth set of a formula is a set of couples, or a set of triples, etc. ( depending on the number of atomic propositions involved in the formula).

To construct your Venn diagram, use as U ( universal set) the set of all possible couples, triples, etc.

Example ( with, by convention, P as first sentence and Q as second sentence)

The truth set of (P&Q) is { (T,T)} ( a set with only one element, for (P&Q) is true in only one case, namely the case in which P is true and Q is also true.

The truth set of (P v Q) is { (T,T), (T,F), (F,T)}

etc.

The formula  (P&Q) => Q is valid ( is a tautology) since it's truth set is :

```
                 { (T,T), (T,F), (F,T), (F,F) }
```

in other words, the formula is valid, since it's truth set is U, the universal set itself ( for a formula involving only 2 atomic sentences)!